# Merge by first column multiple files in the same folder

Tags: r

I have probably a difficult question since I would like to know if there is an elegant way to solve it in R.

Essentially I have a folder full of different tab separated .txt files.

each file has "names" in the first column and the important numerical value in the third column. every file contains the same names, they are just in different rows.

So I was wondering if, with a nice function, I can simplify the task and let R generating a data frame with, in the first column the names (does not matter the order) and in the other columns all the 3rd columns of each single file saved in the same folder (with the name of the files as name of the column)

I am not able to write something decent and I only have a function for merging, because I am not able to make a cycle that whatever files are in the folder, they are all process together.

Answer (score 1):

So you just want the name column and the 3rd column?

Using data.table:

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- fread("text1.txt")[, c(1, 3)]
dt2 <- fread("text2.txt")[, c(1, 3)]
...
```

Repeat for all your txt files, then:

```
dt <- dt1[dt2, on = "name"]
dt <- dt[dt3, on = "name"]
...
```

Repeat for all the files.

That should be sufficient, assuming all third columns are unique data and I'm correct in my assumptions about your data.